# How to use DataCollection and Configuration in Kaa sample applications?

Tags: java, eclipse, kaa

I have made a single node of Kaa Platform, created my first Kaa Application following this link: 
"https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/" 
Now in eclipse, I imported the generated SDK in Java and created an application like:

```
import org.kaaproject.kaa.client.DesktopKaaPlatformContext;
import org.kaaproject.kaa.client.Kaa;
import org.kaaproject.kaa.client.KaaClient;
import org.kaaproject.kaa.client.SimpleKaaClientStateListener;
import org.kaaproject.kaa.client.configuration.base.ConfigurationListener;
import org.kaaproject.kaa.client.configuration.base.SimpleConfigurationStorage;
import org.kaaproject.kaa.client.logging.strategies.RecordCountLogUploadStrategy;
import org.kaaproject.kaa.schema.sample.Configuration;
import org.kaaproject.kaa.schema.sample.DataCollection;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Class implement functionality for First Kaa application. Application send temperature data
 * from the Kaa endpoint with required configured sampling period
 */
public class FirstKaaDemo {

    private static final long DEFAULT_START_DELAY = 1000L;


private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirstKaaDemo.class);

    private static KaaClient kaaClient;

    private static ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;
    private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info(FirstKaaDemo.class.getSimpleName() + " app starting!");

        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        //Create the Kaa desktop context for the application.
        DesktopKaaPlatformContext desktopKaaPlatformContext = new DesktopKaaPlatformContext();

        /*
         * Create a Kaa client and add a listener which displays the Kaa client
         * configuration as soon as the Kaa client is started.
         */
        kaaClient = Kaa.newClient(desktopKaaPlatformContext, new FirstKaaClientStateListener(), true);

        /*
         *  Used by log collector on each adding of the new log record in order to check whether to send logs to server.
         *  Start log upload when there is at least one record in storage.
         */
        RecordCountLogUploadStrategy strategy = new RecordCountLogUploadStrategy(1);
        strategy.setMaxParallelUploads(1);

kaaClient.setLogUploadStrategy(strategy);

        /*
         * Persist configuration in a local storage to avoid downloading it each
         * time the Kaa client is started.
         */
        kaaClient.setConfigurationStorage(new SimpleConfigurationStorage(desktopKaaPlatformContext, "saved_config.cfg"));

        kaaClient.addConfigurationListener(new ConfigurationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigurationUpdate(Configuration configuration) {
                LOG.info("Received configuration data. New sample period: {}", configuration.getSamplePeriod());
                onChangedConfiguration(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(configuration.getSamplePeriod()));
            }
        });

        //Start the Kaa client and connect it to the Kaa server.
        kaaClient.start();

        LOG.info("--= Press any key to exit =--");
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("IOException has occurred: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        LOG.info("Stopping...");

 scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
        kaaClient.stop();
    }

    /*
     * Method, that emulate getting temperature from real sensor.
     * Retrieves random temperature.
     */
    private static int getTemperatureRand() {
        return new Random().nextInt(10) + 25;
    }

    private static void onKaaStarted(long time) {
        if (time <= 0) {
            LOG.error("Wrong time is used. Please, check your configuration!");
            kaaClient.stop();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int temperature = getTemperatureRand();
                        kaaClient.addLogRecord(new DataCollection(temperature));
                        LOG.info("Sampled Temperature: {}", temperature);
                    }
                }, 0, time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

  }

    private static void onChangedConfiguration(long time) {
        if (time == 0) {
            time = DEFAULT_START_DELAY;
        }
        scheduledFuture.cancel(false);

        scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int temperature = getTemperatureRand();
                        kaaClient.addLogRecord(new DataCollection(temperature));
                        LOG.info("Sampled Temperature: {}", temperature);
                    }
                }, 0, time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private static class FirstKaaClientStateListener extends SimpleKaaClientStateListener {

        @Override
        public void onStarted() {
            super.onStarted();
            LOG.info("Kaa client started");
            Configuration configuration = kaaClient.getConfiguration();
            LOG.info("Default sample period: {}", configuration.getSamplePeriod());
            onKaaStarted(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(configuration.getSamplePeriod()));
        }

  @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            super.onStopped();
            LOG.info("Kaa client stopped");
        }
    }
}
```

now it has got some problems with DataCollection and Configuration classes. I even imported the .jar file of DataCollection and Configuration, downloaded from CTL=>Export=>Java Library, but nothing changed. 
for example one of the errors is like: 
"The method getSamplePeriod() is undefined for the type Configuration"

what should I do so my project will recognize the DataCollection and Configuration classes? 
any quick help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the link and created `FirstKaaDemo` in java.
I created new Project in eclipse then created new class `FirstKaaDemo.java` in the new package and copy pasted the code on the page.

Right clicked on the `FirstKaaDemo.java>Build path>configure build path>library> add external jar`
then added Downloaded KaaSDK<....>.jar and slf4j.jar clicked ok
then all the errors were solved and I ran the application. It ran successfully.

Comment: Yea that's right. I did the same thing before and it worked. Thanks for your answer any way